# Android Studio: round off as always to next .5 or .0

Tags: java, android

How can i always round off a number to the next .5 or .0

Example:

2.2 => 2.0

2.9 => 2.5

3.0 => 3.0

I tried it like this:

```
 if ((f2 < 1) && (f2 >= 0.5))
        {
            f2=0.5;
        }

else if ((f2 < 1.5) && (f2 >= 1))
        {
            f2=1;
        }
```

But that's not really efficient, because i got a lot of numbers..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for "rounding in java"? In this case one could *double the source number*, round normally, and divide the result in half (there are some rounding - hah! - issues here though). Also, rounding really only 'makes complete sense' when converting to a *fixed decimal* format, including when displaying as a String.

Answer (score 0):

```
private double roundNum(double myNum){
    int myNumInt = (int)myNum;

    if((myNum - myNumInt)<0.5){            
        return Math.floor(myNum);
    } else {         
        return Math.floor(myNum) + 0.5;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Glad I could help, if this answer helped you please consider accepting it as answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Use **Math.floor(2*x)/2**

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider accepting it as answer. Thanks.